# Can we add an SNS topic from Terraform with Email subscription

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Hi I was wondering if we can add an SNS topic from Terraform with Email subscription.

So it will be easy to setup Alarms and create SNS topic to send alert to an email with one “Terraform apply” command.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform currently has a limitation with the provider using `Email` protocol.

It is unsupported because the endpoint needs to be authorized and does not generate an ARN until the target email address has been validated. This breaks the Terraform model and as a result are not currently supported.

Comment: Previously, email subscriptions were not supported. According to current documents, email subscriptions are now partially supported: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription (check the notes relating to email and unconfirmed subscriptions)

Answer (score 25):

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "topic-name"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "email-target" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "example@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.

Comment: What's to explain? Create a an SNS topic resource, then create a subscription resource. You will need the endpoint email address to confirm the subscription, but the above should work according to the docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription

Comment: @ShadowMan for a list of emails, does it accept comma separated email values or a list? I tried that and seems like its not working, not sure why.

Comment: @AbhayNayak you should try it and find out. The docs just say "an email address", but the field appears to be a string, so a random guess here... Maybe it's just copy/paste thrown into the `To:` field? If so, and assuming it allows multiple email addresses at all, then CSV would likely work. Only way to know for sure is to try it out yourself (you say "I tried that" but you didn't specify if "that" meant both options or only one of them -- it may be that it only accepts a single email address so you'll need to create an email list).

Comment: @AbhayNayak actually, thinking about how confirmations work (see the docs as they mention issues wrt email and unconfirmed subscriptions), it likely will only work with a single email address, so you may have to create an email list for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation supports this.

However, as others and the docs are point out, terraform doesn't quite support it.

There's a guide that suggests creating a CloudFormation stack within terraform. This stack creates the SNS topic and could also add the subscription.

http://aws-cloud.guru/terraform-sns-topic-email-list/

It could be a solution if you think the effort is worth it

Comment: tried this and it worked. but worth noting that you may need to use a different email address than the one used with terraform. in my case, AWS didn't seem to want to pick up that same email address I've used with terraform :/